# Render stl files in asymptote

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I want to draw a propeller in 3D for my fluid dynamics lecture. I found a [3D model of a propeller](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:116410) that can be [downloaded](http://www.thingiverse.com/download:241890) as a [`stl` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)).

I found a python library [`numpy-stl`](https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl) that can read and draw, with the help of matplotlib, the propeller.

[image]

My question is: how can I do to import and draw the polygons in asymptote (a python intermediate step is not a problem: no need to implement a stl parser in asymptote!).

Comment: Look at this previous question:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195210/import-3d-object-in-latex

Comment: @Arianna Indeed. Thanks! The asymtote `obj` library is the answer, provided you can [convert `stl` file to `obj` file](http://www.clementcreusot.com/phd/scripts/stl2obj.py). Feel free to anwser here. I'll try to come with the whole figure when finished.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry, but now I can't figure out how to convert the .stl file in the requested format. Probably you have to use a pre-processing tool or write some code.

Comment: When I download the stl file you link to, it renders as a propellor with only three blades.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, an ascii `stl` file is so simple it's easy to write an Asymptote script to read it directly. Note, however, that the code below is too simple to offer useful feedback in case the `stl` file has errors.

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 8;
import three;
size(20cm);

struct stringpointer { string s; }

surface readstlfile(string filename, stringpointer returnsurfacename=null, bool ascii=true) {
  assert(ascii, "Reading binary stl files not implemented.");
  file stlfile = input(filename).word();  // Set up a file to read whitespace-delimited items.
  string nextword;
  real x, y, z;
  
  nextword = stlfile;  // Reading from a file is done by assignment in Asymptote.
  assert(nextword == "solid", filename + " is not a well-formed stl file.");
  
  string name = stlfile;
  if (returnsurfacename != null) returnsurfacename.s = name;

  surface toreturn;

  while (!eof(stlfile)) {
    nextword = stlfile;
    if (nextword == "endsolid") break;
    else if (nextword == "facet") {

      nextword = stlfile;
      assert(nextword == "normal");

      x = stlfile; y = stlfile; z = stlfile;
      triple normal = (x, y, z);

      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "outer");
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "loop");
      triple[] vertices = new triple[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "vertex");
        x = stlfile; y = stlfile; z = stlfile;
        vertices[i] = (x,y,z);
      }
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "endloop");
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "endfacet");

      patch triangle = patch(vertices[0] -- vertices[1] -- vertices[2] -- cycle);
      triangle.normals = array(4, value=normal);
      toreturn.s.push(triangle);
      
    } else assert(false, filename + " is not a well-formed stl file.");
  }
  assert(nextword == "endsolid", filename + " does not end correctly.");
  nextword = stlfile;
  assert(nextword == name, filename + " does not end with the solid's correct name " + name);
  return toreturn;
}

currentprojection = perspective(-30, 10, 60);
surface propeller = readstlfile("propellerbetter.stl");
draw(propeller, blue);
```

[image: propeller]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot (you clearly deserve a bounty as soon as it is possible).