# Export matplotlib triangle mesh to an asymptote surface

Tags: 3d, asymptote, python, matplotlib

This is a followup of a [question of mine at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34060955/1195799) partially reproduced here for clarity.

I'm playing a bit with [`scikit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/) [marching cubes](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_marching_cubes.html) [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes). Here is a simplified version of the example given in the docs.

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from skimage import measure


x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, x, x, indexing = 'ij')

def f(x, y, z):
    return x

verts, faces = measure.marching_cubes(f(X, Y, Z), 0.6)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces])
ax.add_collection3d(mesh)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_zlim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting surface:

[image]

Now I'd like to draw the surface with asymptote. So basically, I have to find a way to export the coordinates of the triangles. Easy: each triangle is an element of `verts[faces]` represented by 3 lists, the elements being the 3 coordinates of each vertice. So I can parse `verts[faces]` and write to a file `path3 triangle = (x1, y1, z1) -- (x2, y2, z2) -- (x3, y3, z3) -- cycle` for each triangle. Then, for each `triangle`, I draw the surface: `draw(surface(triangle))`. But is there a better way to define the surface for asymptote?

Note that in real life, the surface is far more complex than a simple plane `:)`

Comment: I know that my question is very near off topic. But it is directly related to asymptote and people are nice here!

Comment: I'm unsure whether this very well phrased question question is [on topic](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/are-asymptote-questions-on-topic)... I better upvote it ;)

Comment: Just a thought - Asymptote has an obj module to construct surfaces from .obj files. You can export your triangles to the .obj format, the spec is available online, and plot the surface this way.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282390/484, specifically `surface toreturn` and the three lines beginning `patch triangle =`. (Only ignore the line about normals, that has been removed since I wrote that answer.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats I have a solution based on your comment. Do you want to answer or should I answer myself?

Comment: Please answer yourself.