# Export asymptote 3D arrows

Tags: asymptote

For 3D figures, I use [asymptote](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote) and [blender](https://www.blender.org/). Usually, I don't draw arrows in blender because I use it mostly for more "artistic views". But, from time to time, I need one. For consistency, I'd like to use the same 3D arrows as in asymptote.

Is there a way to export those arrows in a [compatible format](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/import_export.html) (probably `.obj` or `.stl`)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but FYI, the other way around has been kinda addressed.
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282106/render-stl-files-in-asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282106/render-stl-files-in-asymptote)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Any ideas?

Comment: @g.kov Any ideas?