# Change pgfplots shading and coloring of patch plots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195258/180429), I want to insert a solid model of some complicated geometry into my LaTeX document.

The default coloring for the facets is based on its average z value. The higher the facet is - the "larger" color is used based on the color map.

I want to change it, so the colors would be selected according to how lighted or shadowed the part of the object is.

For example, I want to draw a simple cylinder in my LaTeX document.

This is how it looks with Wolfram's Mathematica:

[image]

created with `Graphics3D[{CapForm[None], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}]`.

I converted this Graphics object to an `stl` file and converted this file to a `dat` file, that [can be found here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2253330).

The result with PGFPlots is the following:

[image]

Is there any way to make it appear more "realistic", regarding shadowing, where the light source is located etc.?

LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis equal]
    \addplot3 [patch,shader=interp] file
      {cylinder.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "light source" in PGF. Nobody has implemented ray tracing in TeX yet and I sincerely hope nobody ever will.

Comment: Also vector graphics cannot be ray traced. Ray tracing relies inherently on rasterization. Better just export the graph from Mathematica with labels typeset using [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).

Comment: O.k. So without implementing ray tracing, is there any possibility to choose the color range not to be based on the z value?

Comment: Yes, by reading the manual.

Comment: As it is, it is not possible to answer the question as it is not about making the cylinder appear like the picture or about making functional coloring. Apparently the cylinder is just a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about "realistic" - this is the wrong forum for realism! Here is a coloring of a cylinder as a function of `x`, `y` and `z`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
domain=0:1,
y domain=0:360,
samples=2,
samples y=50,
point meta={abs(rawx+rawy+0.2*rawz)},
colormap={whiteblue}{color=(blue!50) color=(brown!50!black)}
] ( {cos(\y)} , {sin(\y)}, \x );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded cylinder]

Comment: Very Nice! But, this question I am asking is about plotting complicated solid models in a LaTeX document, with the aid of a `dat` file. The very simple object I uploaded is just for the case of an example. I actually want to insert a plot of a much more complicated model I am working on with a CAD software.

Comment: @tush: I do not understand. The solution should not be dependent on how you make the plot. I am not willing to download extra unneeded files.

Comment: If I understand, your approach would produce a "good looking" cylinder. But what about a more complicated object, like the airplane shown in the answer I linked to?

Comment: For a more complicated model you could try the same function to see if is acceptable. -or a more complicated function. I can not help with that because I do not know, it depends on *a lot* and because this is not the correct forum.